# What is the proper way to create draft page programatically in the Wagtail?

Tags: django, wagtail, revision, addchild

Just to save page I do:

```
parent_page = Page.objects.get(title="parent")
page = Page(title="child", owner=request.user)
parent_page.add_child(instance=page)
page.save() # not sure if this required
```

What if I need to save Draft Page? This code seems to be working but I am not sure if it's correct:

```
parent_page = Page.objects.get(title="parent")
page = Page(title="child", live=False, owner=request.user)
parent_page.add_child(instance=page)
page.save_revision()
page.save()
```

Do I need call page.save() after page.save_revision()?

With this code everything works ok in my case but I have noticed that PageRevision.user_id is empty. How it can affect my code in future?
From wagtail code I see that I can save revision with user parameter:

```
page.save_revision(user=request.user, log_action=True)
```

I have saved revisions without user and don't see any side effect. How this field is critical? Do I need to fill user_id field for all existing revisions?

P.S. looks like it would be better to wrap this code in transaction because when it fails due to validation error `manage.py fixtree` show me error `Incorrect numchild value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `page.save()` in either case - `parent_page.add_child` handles the saving. (This might be what's causing the `manage.py fixtree` issue - [django-treebeard doesn't update in-memory instances after database operations](https://django-treebeard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/caveats.html#raw-queries), so fields like `numchild` may be getting saved with incorrect values.)

The `user` field on revisions is optional, because changes to pages are not always performed by users - they might be done programmatically, like you are doing. It's just there for logging purposes (e.g. to show in the revision history of a page in the Wagtail admin).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't need history for those pages so can I assume then that I don't need revision at all? I mean is it safe to create draft page without revision? Also as I said my pure experience with this code tells me to wrap code into  transaction. It could be easily done in django with: decorator `@transaction.atomic` or context manager `with transaction.atomic()`.

Comment: No, you don't need revision objects - the editing interface will fall back on editing the 'real' page object if none are found.